unable to decode encrypted bytes data stored in db
I have written 2 functions in python, one for encrypting data and other for decrypting data which are as follows.
from app.settings import DATA_KEY
import logging
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.aead import AESSIV
import base64

cipher_suite = AESSIV(DATA_KEY)

error_logger = logging.getLogger("error_logger")


def encrypt_field(input_text):
    try:
        if isinstance(input_text, str):
            input_text = input_text.encode()
        enc_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(input_text, associated_data = None)
        print(f"enc_text is {enc_text}")
        enc_text_base_64 = base64.b64encode(enc_text)
        print(f"encrypted_text is {enc_text_base_64}")
        return enc_text_base_64
    
    except Exception as e:
        error_logger.error(f"exception in encrypt field {str(e)} on field {input_text}")
        return input_text


def decrypt_field(input_text):
    try:
        print(f"input in decrypt field is {input_text} its type is {type(input_text)}")
        enc_text = base64.b64decode(input_text)
        print(f"enc text is {enc_text}")
        decrypted_field = cipher_suite.decrypt(enc_text, associated_data = None)
        print(f"decrypted_field is {decrypted_field}")
        return decrypted_field.decode('utf-8')
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        error_logger.error(f"exception in decrypt_field {e} on field {input_text}")
        return input_text
    
    

I am able to encrypt and store the data in db, however upon reading the data from db and trying to decrypt it, I am getting a utf-8 bytestring instead of original plaintext string back. What am I doing wrong here?
My Django version is 5.0, Python version is 3.10.11 and Database is PostgreSQL.
This is how I am trying to decrypt the values after reading the data using queryset
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        
        fields = ['username', 'email']

    def get_username(self, obj):
        return decrypt_field(obj.username)
    
    def get_email(self, obj):
        return decrypt_field(obj.email)

and this is my model
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    password_reset_required = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    username_field = "email"

on calling the decrypt function instead of original email and username that I've supplied

redgrave@example.com

I instead get

"b'CSPex4eChMQousC2Sn5JBCvge6j2X73iiQIZ5O5l9d2AliVBWiPGoGe5pKVTzEVAlIYcBxbe+1gufGXhnIQKCQ=='"

I have tried storing the data in BinaryField as well TextField of Django models, by adding additional fields to model wit binary and TextField as datatype. but to no avail the result is same. I have tried storing data as encoded byte data without base64encde as well but it cannot be decoded later and results in undefined character error.

Do you have a good reason to use the hazardous-materials AESSIV module instead of Fernet which would do everything for you?

Yes I need encrypted result to be deterministic for same key and input that's why I am using AESSIV module instead of Fernet. As using Fernet was generating different ciphertext for same key and input, which I came know is by design.

The posted code works on my machine (encryption and decryption without DB). So the data may be corrupted when saving to/loading from DB. Check if both key and ciphertext during encryption are the same as during decryption. Post these values for non-productive test data.

BTW, the data can be stored in the DB as text because of the Base64 encoding (enc_text_base_64.decode()). If they are to be stored as binary instead, Base64 encoding/decoding is not actually required.

"b'CSPex4 is the smoking gun... As documented base64.b64encode() returns a bytes (that just so happens to only contain ASCII bytes). Something (maybe Django, maybe you) is calling str() on a bytes object and you get a string that's the repr of a bytes (and those start with b', since that's how Python represents bytes for humans). See my answer – I explicitly decode the base64 bytes as ASCII so it's strings back and forth.

Your answer works outside of Django I am able to get the original plaintext back, it however does not work with Django and unfortunately does not raise any error as well. Just returns the byte object as included in edit of the question.

When you're converting your string to bytes you aren't specifying any encoding: input_text.encode() but when you do vice-versa you've explicitly specified UTF-8: decrypted_field.decode('utf-8') do note that UTF-8 is not always the default encoding and that it depends on the OS being used.

Next don't make us guess at your implementation, give us a proper [mre], which means saving an object to the database, fetching it and then getting the value of the field back all should be part of the code you share. Remove that serializer, if you think the problem is happening when used with the DB just drop into a shell (python manage.py shell) run some code to create objects, try to get the value back if it fails share that code as your [mre]. If it doesn't then add the part about the relevant views / serializers in.

I think you can simply simplify your implementation:
import base64

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.aead import AESSIV

DATA_KEY = b"ABCDEFGH" * 4  # VERY SECRET!
cipher_suite = AESSIV(DATA_KEY)


def encrypt_text_to_base64(input_text: str) -> str:
    if not isinstance(input_text, str):
        raise TypeError("Input must be text")
    enc_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(input_text.encode("utf-8"), associated_data=None)
    return base64.b64encode(enc_text).decode("ascii")


def decode_base64_to_text(input_text: str | bytes) -> str:
    return cipher_suite.decrypt(
        base64.b64decode(input_text), associated_data=None
    ).decode("utf-8")


plain = "Hello, world!"
encrypted = encrypt_text_to_base64(plain)
encrypted_bytes = encrypted.encode("utf-8")
decrypted = decode_base64_to_text(encrypted)
decrypted_from_bytes = decode_base64_to_text(encrypted_bytes)

print(f"{plain=}")
print(f"{encrypted=}")
print(f"{encrypted_bytes=}")
print(f"{decrypted=}")
print(f"{decrypted_from_bytes=}")


try:
    print(decode_base64_to_text("f" + encrypted[1:]))
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to decrypt tampered data:", repr(e))


This prints out
plain='Hello, world!'
encrypted='1mtatTQy3/GRFv0tUd3Mp66V8uDbeKDqn8rKytU='
encrypted_bytes=b'1mtatTQy3/GRFv0tUd3Mp66V8uDbeKDqn8rKytU='
decrypted='Hello, world!'
decrypted_from_bytes='Hello, world!'
Failed to decrypt tampered data: InvalidTag()

so you can see the decryption function works for both base64-in-bytes and base64-as-a-string.

Thank you for the suggestion, but my concern is why when reading data from db and trying to decrypt it does not give the original plaintext and how do I fix it, I have tried your code as well, but it results in string argument without an encoding error when trying to save the object to DB using Django ORM.

This is just string-to-string – you should well be able to store the resulting string in a TextField. It's also quite impossible for you to get a wrong text; if the AESSIV embedded MAC is incorrect, cryptography will raise an exception.

Yes, I tried it with a text field as well, but when reading the data from db and trying to decrypt it, I am unable to get the original plaintext back. My Guess is decrypt is failing, but where and how is what I am unable to pinpoint.

What do you mean "unable to get the original plaintext back"? If you're using your implementation, try without the try/excepts and tell us what the exception is. As said, there is no way for AESSIV to return a wrong text – it returns the original plaintext if the key is correct, or raises.

I figured out the issue, turns out encryption was being called on email field twice once from view and once from create method which I was unaware of, I tried the same functions with different fields and table and it works flawlessly. Also I implemented your approach to store data in base64encoded format.
